# None of the Windows Store apps show up in application list

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-preview, windows-store-app

I'm using Windows 10 Insider Preview, build 14291.

There are random freezes on this build, during one of those freezes, I restarted my pc as usual but when I restarted, it opened up in a "temporary profile" and said that I can't use my files and I had to access internet and relog, I did that and everything seems fine, except one thing: None of the Windows Store apps show up in Application List in both storage part of settings (< which usually crashes) and in start menu. If I launch them using store (which I open by clicking an install link online on Windows Store), they don't show up in taskbar too.

[I tried using this](https://solutions.diagnostics.support.microsoft.com/run/6b089dc3-50d6-4add-9959-337fca72c533#) but it didn't work. Win+G game menu seems to work. Installing new apps from Store work, [they show up on app list and taskbar](https://0ws.pw/417w.png). Deployments from Visual Studio work.

How can I fix this issue (get my apps to show up on start menu again)?

Comment: Please leave your questions here on comments, I'll try to reply them when I wake up in 6 hours.

Comment: Currently testing out " Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` fixed it.